# Cannot handle popup newsletter

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to test an E-Commerce website using Selenium webdriver. The problem in the test is that whenever I try to add stuff in the cart it just pops a news letter window which I tried handling using alert but I cannot.

Can someone please help me. I am attaching a screenshot below along with the code.

[image]

```
public class Ui {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/New folder/geckodriver.exe");
        //First Iam going to initialize the webdriver by using Firefox driver//
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.build.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='search_txt']")).sendKeys("K-6626-6U ");  
         Actions enter = new Actions(driver);
         enter.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='site-search']/div/button"))).click().build().perform();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use xpath to handle it. If it is iframe, use iframe code to handle it.

Comment: @Hozefa, If any answer helpful to you then please accept it So it be helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

First thing is - Its not an alert it a window popup So you need to locate the close button and then click

Use below code for the same :

```
public class Ui 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/New folder/geckodriver.exe");
        //First Iam going to initialize the webdriver by using Firefox driver//
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.build.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf( driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='close external-close']")))).click();
    }
}
```

Here you have to use `ExplicitWait` until  popup get visible and then have to perform click. If you won't use the wait then it will throw `ElementNotVisibleException`.

Answer (score 0):

wait for some time and click on escape

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.build.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //give own time
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Actions enter = new Actions(driver);
    enter.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform();
}
```